# Spark Streaming with Kafka performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

What are the approaches to improve shuffling performance in Spark Streaming?
Basically, I am using Spark Streaming(1.6.2) with Kafka(0.10) to crunch 100s of Petabytes of data per day and as because of the data velocity is very huge it's getting pretty tough to stabilize the entire Streaming application.
Performed all the code level optimization and reduce the shuffle.
Looking for some core tuning configuration to at least improve the shuffling performance.

Comment: Please share your code or minimal reproducible example - it will be easier to help you

Comment: There is nothing much transformations I am performing currently but just adding few flags to the incoming Kafka record.Its taking too much time to save the rdd into HDFS as because the data size is huge per 60sec batch.As because there are a limited number of Kafka partitions available which is beyond our reach,  currently we are unable t increase the parallelism as well which leads to underutilized cluster resources.

Comment: val stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String]( streamingContext, PreferConsistent, Assign[String, String](fromOffsets.keys.toList, kafkaParams, fromOffsets) ) 
stream.foreachRDD { rdd => 
val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
val processedRDD = rdd.map(----some tranformation----) 
processedRDD.saveAsTextFile(---) 
//commit offset to external data source 
stream.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
 }